# android sync adapter Security Exception

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, securityexception

**Error**

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10184 cannot get secrets
>   for accounts of type:

**Code**

```
    @Nullable
    public static Account getSyncAccount(Context context)
    {
    AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);

    Account newAccount  = new Account(context.getString(R.string.app_name), context.getString(R.string.content_authority));

    assert accountManager != null;
    if(null == accountManager.getPassword(newAccount))
    {
if(!accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount,"",null))  //Error here
        {
            return null;
        }
        onAccountCreated(newAccount,context);
    }

    return newAccount;
}
```

**Authenticator Service**

```
    <service android:name=".sync.ProductAuthenticatorService">
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator"/>
    </service>


    <!-- Sync Adapter Service -->
    <service android:name=".sync.ProductSyncService"
        android:exported="true"
        >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>

    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
        android:resource="@xml/syncadapter"/>
    </service>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation, what are you trying to achieve and what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

To your Manifest should solve your `SecurityException`.

(Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), if an app shares the signature of the authenticator that manages an account, it does not need "GET_ACCOUNTS" permission to read information about that account. On Android 5.1 and lower, all apps need "GET_ACCOUNTS" permission to read information about any account.)